# Android PreferenceList, sublist after a choice

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-preferences, listpreference

I'm looking for a way to show a second list in a preference, after a user has selected a choice in a listpreference

For example : the user selects the option "Send sms to" from a list, then a second list appears, and the user can choose a contact.

At the moment, i'm trying to put a onSharedPreferenceChanged method from my preference activity, and show an alert Dialog containing the contacts after a selection, but i think there is another way... But i havent found it yet on the Internet...

Does anyone know how it is possible ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `PreferenceActivity` put a method like below that listens for when that specific key is clicked.

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {

    //Make sure the item changed was the list_preference 
    if(key.equals("list_preference")) {
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "Nothing");

        if(value.equals("Send_sms")) {
            //launch AlertDialog with list or launch new preference 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's, that's what i'm at the moment implementing. I was wondering if there were a built-in-way to do it (only with preferences), but that's why i'm gona do if you also suggest me to do that :)

Comment: There is no built in way that I am aware of. On StackOverflow when you are satisfied with an answer, you usually accept it by clicking the checkbox next to that answer. This is so the answer gets the person credit and helps future viewers of the post.